# With the Javascript event onbeforeunload, is it possible to do anything other than an alert dialog?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload, yahoo-api, onunload

In all of the sample code I have seen, it appears that the only function of onbeforeunload is to serve up an alert dialog box prior to the person leaving the page. Is that the only thing that can be triggered by the event or is it possible to do something else, like an unobtrusive function that sends off partial form data?

I am trying to capture abandoned shopping carts in Yahoo! Small Business and unfortunately I do not have access to any server side scripting, so I'm forced to work client-side only.

I was also thinking of doing an ajax posting of data after the email field was changed, and then comparing the list of all forms partially submitted against completed carts to determine which were incomplete.

Comment: I've used `onbeforeunload` to fire off synchronous AJAX, and it's worked.  But I don't think it's guaranteed to work. and might be subject to a short timeout.  I wouldn't use it for anything mission-critial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the partial form data in `localStorage`. Then, when another page is loaded, you could check for the presence of that data and AJAX it to the server, deleting it from `localStorage` on success. Or you might be able to just use that data in JavaScript, without involving the server, but that depends on your setup.

Comment: As Niet says, this is a strong use case for onBeforeUnload. Storing shopping cart data, position in a media file, etc.

Comment: @Niet I found a demo over at http://www.jkirchartz.com that has a HTML5 notepad that autosaves to localstorage when any change is made, or after a few hundred milliseconds, or on page close. It reloads the data when the user comes back showing what had been typed. Is it possible to modify this to AJAX the data to our server?

Answer (score 1):

`<body onbeforeunload="return ('You will lose all your data')" onunload="alert('You have gone away!')">
</body>`

`Onbeforeunload` uses for alert box. `Onunload` for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* technically fire off an ajax event, but there is **no guarantee** that it will complete before the page is actually reloaded.